# Statistical Analysis of GPX Files

Tags: data-visualization, gps

I have a number of GPX files upon which I would like to perform some statistical 
analysis.

The sort of thing I am after is to extract journeys from A to B where different routes 
have been taken, and summarize the journey times.  Then perform some analysis of statistically the best route at different times of day and/or days of the week.

Ideally, something that will take a directory full of GPX files and will produce a report.  However, as that is probably wishful thinking, something that can produce a CSV file or similar with timing fields, waypoints and other data will be fine.  I can than massage that separately.

I'm not after simply showing the GPX tracks on a map.  It is the extraction that is key.  Does anything like this exist?  I haven't been able to find it.

I'm also open about the OS platform,  Windows for preference but I have access to Apples 
and various Linux boxes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three months after posting the question, the nearest thing I have found to an answer is [GPS Visualizer](http://gpsvisualizer.com/).

A website to which you can upload a number of GPX files and which will return a CSV file containing the tracks and waypoints.  This can then be read into a spreadsheet and analyzed separately.

Answer (score 3):

How much detail do you want to get out of those GPX files?

If it's related to distance/total ascent (profile related stats), you can use [gpx2kml.com](http://gpx2kml.com)

It is free and you can store your tracks for future analysis.
Even if you have them all in a list, it will not aggregate data.
Or, you can join your tracks within one file and see the stats displayed after a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [My GPS Files](http://www.mygpsfiles.com/) which can do some of what you want.

Primarily for visualising overlaid tracks on a map, it will output aggregated data.